# How to serialize/deserialize a binaryheap in Lua?

Tags: lua

```
local binaryheap = require 'binaryheap'
local cjson = require "cjson.safe"

local heap = binaryheap.minUnique()

heap:insert(22, 'foo')
heap:insert(13, 'bar')
heap:insert(14, 'fubar')


local str = cjson.encode(heap)
heap = cjson.decode(str)
local mylow = heap:peek()
```

I hope this explain what I am trying to do.

Can it be done without dumping all the data and recreating the heap?

I would like to save my binaryheap to storage and get it back later. Is this possible?

The binary heap module come from here: https://github.com/Tieske/binaryheap.lua

Comment: One very common implementation of binary heaps is with an array. In this case, it should be easy to serialize. It all depends where you got `binaryheap` from.